# NGINX IngressController - how to do simple 302 Redirects?

Tags: nginx-ingress

I would like to do a redirect from some/old/url to some/new/url - the simplest of cases. No other host or different domain, no wildcards, no RegEx, just the simple case that a URL has changed.

There is a lot of documentation out there for [very complex URL rewrites](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), which is not what I want at all. There should be no rewriting of the URL plus the redirect should be subject to a defined ingress rule, not an annotation that applies to the entire ingress. The server should send a 302 to the browser with the new URL in the Location header and this should happen before any backend services are called. Here is my ingress rule:

```
  rules:
    - host: 'myhost.mydomain.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Ideally there would be a way to define a second path that has precedence over / and does not go to a backend service, but sends a 302 redirect to the new URL instead (which will then get to the backend service via the / rule).